# Hide router in ngx-admin based on user permissions?

Tags: angular, router, ngx-admin

Hide route in ngx-admin based on user permissions?. The user chooses the plans. Based on his plan, hide some routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your routes with `ngif` based on user's plan and you can check if user can navigate that route with `Guard`.

Read the Angular documentation about that: [Angular Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)